# Python Return multiple variables after pause in function

Tags: python, html, function, flask

I have found a piece of flask: https://github.com/pratik55/Python-Flask-dynamic-update- code that dynamically updates the HTML, but it requires a function like time.time() - it outputs, pauses, and outputs again. I would like a custom function to do just this but not with a time value.

I tried something similar to this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-41-multiple-return-values-in-python/ but I could not put a pause in between each output.

The flask code looks like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
import webbrowser
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/_stuff', methods = ['GET'])
def stuff():

    return jsonify(result=time.time())


@app.route('/')
def index():

    return render_template('dy1.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run()
```

The result is just a question mark when I replace result=time.time() with something else unless its very explicit like result="hello"

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  What are you actually trying to return?  What does your real code look like?

Comment: Basically I need a function that can return pause and return